# Developer story timeline card/"cog"/edit bug

Tags: bug, developer-story

When updating something on a card in the developer story, upon clicking the save button, the state IS saved... but the edit-cog disappears until the page is refreshed.

[image: A gif that took way too long to make]

Environment:

> - Google Chrome `Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)`
> - OSX